# Adding Ruby Gems to NetBeans-- activation problem

Tags: netbeans, jruby

I have been programming Java in NetBeans for a long while, but I just bought the book “Using JRuby” (really well-written) and came to the point where the example in the book needed the gem Rubeus. I downloaded it, went to Tools/Ruby Gems in NetBeans, and managed to get it installed (or so it appeared) successfully. Then I tried to run the example code, but I get the nastygram below:

/jruby1.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:812:in `report_activate_error’: Could not find RubyGem activesupport (= 2.1.2) (Gem::LoadError)
from /jruby1.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:223:in`activate'

(and further stack trace lines)

So apparently a gem needs to be activated, even after it’s installed. How do I do that?

Thanks in advance for any help.

John Doner

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that error has anything to do with Rubeus, but I don't know what Rubeus does. It's complaining that it can't find the ActiveSupport gem.

You do not need to active gems. Typically you install them on the command line with `gem install some_gem`